# Kalman Filter Convergence Time

Tags: bayesian-network, kalman-filter

For a time invariant system, is it possible to guarantee a convergence time that Kalman Filter error covariance reaches the steady state value. if it is possible, then how can we set that convergence time ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can probably do is to look at the resulting error dynamics $\dot e(t)=Ae(t)$ ($A$ is the closed-loop matrix) and estimate its convergence to zero. The basic solution here is an exponential $e^{i Re\lambda_k t}$ where $\lambda_k$ is en eigenvalue of $A$. The slowest exponent (the largest negative Re$\lambda$) will affect the convergence the most.

Comment: i'm not sure, i think its like an observer design argument, but Kalman filter may have difference from an observer considering process noise. i.e choosing R and Q matrices may effect the convergence time..

Comment: I do not remember exactly, it was way too many years ago, but I feel like the Kalman filter is an observer with a special matrix gain that comes from the matrix Riccati equation. The closed-loop matrix $A$ then depends on the original system matrix and on R, Q too. But you can calculate it and find out their eigenvalues.